# How to read appsettings.json from Azure Functions using Azure CLI PowerShell

Tags: azure-functions, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I am using the Azure CLI to interact with my Azure Functions. I want to be able to read the `appsettings.json` file that was deployed with the function app. You can see this file if you're using the App Service Editor.

[image]

From what I have seen so far, I could use the `az functionapp config appsettings set` command but that will only read the appsettings on the function app and not the custom `appsettings.json` file.

How would one go in accomplishing this?

Comment: Have you try my solution? Any doubts about that?

Answer (score 2):

Although I don't recommend doing this on Azure, if you really want to know, I think this should meet your requirements:

**Get the content:**

```
$json = Get-Content 'appsettings.json' | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
```

**Show the content:**

```
$json
```

**Add the value:**

```
$json | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name 'Key' -Value 'Value'
$json | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content 'appsettings.json'
```